Android 13+: Media3: MediaSession default notification - how to get callback on dismiss / swipe of default media notification
In Android 13+/API 33+ Media3: MediaSessionService creates a Notification.MediaStyle by default.
When the MediaNotification is dismissed/swiped the audio keeps playing. I want to stop audio when the media notification is removed.
(Using: androidx.media3:media3-session:1.4.0
on Android 14 physical device)
API 34: I was not able to change the notification in Android 14 by using MediaSessionService .setMediaNotificationProvider() with DefaultMediaNotificationProvider (which implements MediaNotification.Provider)
The idea was to set an .setDeleteIntent(dismissIntent) which works with other notifications.
API 35: Swipping is sometimes not possible (a settings symbol appears right/left). Sometimes it is possible, but the audio keeps playing and the notification appears again automatically.
Any idea what way to go here to stop audio when the notification is swiped?

I am looking for same logic with my app.

See about overriding the onTaskRemoved method
